# Excel changes loadbehaviour of add-in

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

I created an Excel VSTO add-in, which users can install. However, after using the add-in, the next time Excel is started, the add-in is no longer loaded automatically.

The user can resolve this by enabling the add-in, but it happens every time, and I would like to stop that.

What happens is that in te registry, the key:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\TiaGenerator\LoadBehavior` is set to 2, which means inactive by default. I can change it back to 3 (load on startup), but after running Excel, it is changed back to 2.

Edit:
As @Cindy Meister said: Excel should change load behavior to 3 after startup, so there must be a problem. After some searching, it turned out the problem lies within the constructor of a self made class called ErrorWriter. The problem seems to be within this call:

```
Public Class Errorwriter
    Inherits IO.StreamWriter

Sub New()
    MyBase.New("C:\tmp\newLog.txt")

End Sub
End Class
```

Does anyone know why this causes Excel to change the load behavior?

Comment: Sounds like your policies (possibly your company policies) maybe reverting your registry keys. Have you tried talking to help desk to look into this?

Comment: @Zac No, but I think Excel does it based on the load times of the add in, because if I remove some stuff from the load handler, it seems the add-in is no longer disabled...

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by **load handler**.. I suspect that this is beyond my knowledge of excel. I'll keep an eye on this thread just to see if there is a solution. Good luck

Comment: @Zac It is the event handler for the 'Me.Startup' event of the add-in. Basically the constructor for the entire add-in.

Comment: Ahh, right. thanks for clarification

Comment: according to the documentation, Load behavior 2 means: "The application does not try to load the VSTO Add-in automatically. The user can try to manually load the VSTO Add-in, or the VSTO Add-in can be loaded programmatically. If the application successfully loads the VSTO Add-in, the LoadBehavior value changes to 3, and remains at 3 after the application closes." I interpret this to mean that something's wrong with some of your code in Startup. You say taking part of it out resolves the problem. You need to inspect that more closely. Without knowing what this is, no one here can help.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you for your comment, I updated the question with some more details as what code is executed at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of @Cindy Meister, I was able to dig a little bit deeper and here is what I found:

Apperantly, Excel changes the load behaviour of an Add-in if it encounters an unhandled exception during startup.

In the startup routine, I create a new instance of an 'ErrorWriter' object, which inherits from 'StreamWriter', and uses a reference to this file.

What happens is that Excel is loaded, an locks this file. Upon using some functions of this add-in, a second Excel instance is started in the background, which tries to use this file as well. This results in an unhandled exception, but because this second instance is not visible, this error is never shown to the user (nor the programmer).

Because the ErrorWriter is not needed in the second instance of Excel, it never becomes clear that the error occeured in any way.

This causes Excel to change its load behavior.

It is fixed by moving the offending code into a seperate function, which is only called upon invoking add-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have thoroughly investigated the problem and found a solution. Changing the "LoadBehavior" is the right way of doing it, but you have to be careful about one thing. Both Outlook or Excel restore the previous settings for each add-in. BUT not at the start of the add-in but AFTER the add-in's start up.

In other words if you attempt to change the LoadBehavior in Windows Registry as part of the startup it will never work. You have to do it afterwards.

I hope this will help.
Thank you, VJ